# Using NodeJS NFC Reading library pcsclite, how to read multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nfc

I am using the sample nfc reading library from:

https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/node-pcsclite

I am able to read NFC ones, but from the second read, it doesnt work.

i tried to remove the foloowing lines:

```
                    reader.close();
                    pcsc.close();
```

but it still didnt work, just got a new exception:

> /node_modules/pcsclite/lib/pcsclite.js:125
>       this._transmit(data, res_len, protocol, cb);
>            ^
>   Error: Third argument must be an integer

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.transmit(
    new Buffer([0x00, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20]),
    40,
    protocol,
    function(err, data))
```

You have to pass `protocol` as third argument.